# One or more foreign keys created in Create table statement Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, an employee table and a project table. Each project has to have at least one employee, but it could have more. I'm struggling to figure out how to create the Project table so you can have a non-fixed number of foreign keys. What I have right now is this:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
EmployeeID number(10) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar2(20),
LastName varchar2(20),
Address varchar2(20),
City varchar2(20),
State varchar2(2),
Zip number(5),
DoB varchar2(10),
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
Values ('1', 'Joe', 'Smith', '1 Main St', 'Stillwater', 'OK', 74075, '07/05/1992');

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
Values ('2', 'John', 'Johnson', '3 College Way', 'Stillwater', 'OK', 74074, '08/05/1992');

CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
    ProjectID number(10) NOT NULL,
    ProjectName varchar2(20),
    ProjectDesc varchar2(20),
    ProjectStartDate varchar2(20),
    EmployeeID number(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeID FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID)
    REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID)
);

INSERT INTO Project
Values ('1', 'ProjectA', 'A Project', '12/05/2017', '1');

INSERT INTO Project
Values ('2', 'ProjectB', 'B Project', '01/05/2018', '1', '2');
```

Obviously, the last line is where it goes wrong, because there are too many pieces of information. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Obsidian Age gave a great answer. In addition, research cardinality and granularity. It may help you rethink the database model, especially how you build the project table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `values` directly correlate to the fields in the table, and you need to ensure that the number of `values` you insert correctly corresponds to the number of fields.

In order to insert more than one row into the relevant table, you have to split up the inserts. So, you need to split up your two employee insertions into `ProjectB`, and insert both employee independently.

Note that you'll also want to ensure that both of your primary keys auto increment, so that you don't have to worry about the foreign key constraints! In Oracle, you can do this with the **[`IDENTITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA109)** column:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  EmployeeID number(10) NOT NULL as IDENTITY,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT (
  ProjectID number(10) NOT NULL as IDENTITY,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (ProjectID)
);
```

Then you can insert with:

```
INSERT INTO Project Values (null, 'ProjectB', 'B Project', '01/05/2018', '1');
INSERT INTO Project Values (null, 'ProjectB', 'B Project', '01/05/2018', '2');
```

This gives you a total of three `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO Project Values (null, 'ProjectA', 'A Project', '12/05/2017', '1');
INSERT INTO Project Values (null, 'ProjectB', 'B Project', '01/05/2018', '1');
INSERT INTO Project Values (null, 'ProjectB', 'B Project', '01/05/2018', '2');
```

Note that because the employee is the only thing changing in your two inserts to `ProjectB`, you might want to consider looping over these inserts:

```
    DECLARE
    i    NUMBER (1);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. x
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO Project Values ('2', 'ProjectB', 'B Project', '01/05/2018', i);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

However, down the line, I can envisage multiple projects can have multiple employees, and employees working on multiple projects. This would be a **many to many** relationship, which would require a [**bridging table**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) (also know as  associative entity). It may be worthwhile keeping this in mind :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect, I was so focused on doing it the complicated wrong way I didn't even think of just entering it multiple times with different data!

Comment: One other question, if I'm inserting a project multiple times into my table, how to I get around violating uniqueness for my Primary Key?

Comment: Ideally you should make the key `auto increment` on the table itself, and then set the value to `null` while crafting your `INSERT`. This way the insertions will automatically have the next highest integer available :)

Comment: Would that not mean that the same project is referenced by multiple different primary keys?

Comment: No; the `Projects` table will have many primary keys, and each individual `Project` will have a unique primary key. It's essentially the same as running `INSERT ID 1`, followed by `INSERT ID 2`.

Comment: Okay, after rereading your updated answer it cracked it open for me. I ended up creating a billing table that served as a bridging table, so I just created each employee and project once, without referencing each other (like no FKs in projects).
Then I created my billing table where I created billingIDs, rates, and then also had employeeIDs as FKs and projectIDs as foreign keys. Thus, if I need to add a person to a project, I just do it in the billing table.
Thank you for your great answer!